# Downgrade from Yosemite to Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

Few days, ago I bought my first MacBook Pro (late 2013) with preinstalled Mavericks. It worked really great until I updated to Yosemite. Now everything is slow and – more importantly – some tools required for my job are not working.

I must downgrade to Mavericks.

Unfortunately it is not that easy: I can't download Mavericks from the App Store because of Yosemite being installed currently. And I've tried to get 'clean' files from torrents (Mavericks 10.9.1 and 10.9) but after creating a bootable USB stick (with DiskMaker X 4b4) I see a big "circle slash" and installation doesn't start.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to restore from your backup, but it sounds like you don't have that? What happens exactly when you boot from the stick? Is that where the circle appears?

Comment: Yep :( i dont have one.

Comment: Now i managed to run installator but then i get that error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8629281/

Comment: Ok i erased disk and installation went successfully :)

Comment: Great. You should post your solution as an answer, maybe with some specific steps! :)